# Count Clicks and update Mysql

Tags: php

i try to complete a click counter. Whats wrong with my code? It doesnt count the hits on link.

```
$id             =   $_GET['song_id'];
$query          =   "SELECT * FROM store WHERE id = '$id'";
$result         =   mysql_query($query);
$row            =   mysql_fetch_array($result);
$strSQL         =   "Select hits from store WHERE id = '$id'";
$htop_tabelle   =   mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query($strSQL));
$hits           =   $htop_tabelle->hits;
$hits++;
$insertSQL      =   "UPDATE store SET hits = $hits WHERE id = '$id'";
$htop_tabelle   =   mysql_query($insertSQL);

mysql_close() or die ("Nicht getrennt");
```

the link is

```
<a href="http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/download_window_youtube_mobil.php?song_id=<?= $store->id ?>"><?= $store->artist .' - '. $store->song ?></a>
```

i think the problem is in defining the GET for this `<?= $store->id ?>`

please help me

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are you on a PHP version where `<?=` is always on or at least enabled?

Comment: Please, don't use the mysql_* functions - use PDO or mysqli_* instead. What would happen if I click this link: http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/download_window_youtube_mobil.php?song_id=0';%20DELETE%20FROM%@20store;'

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks!

Comment: read this to understand doing PDO http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html

Comment: someone can say me, why my code is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to read the current hits value and increment it in PHP then try to save it back to the database.  Let the database  server do all the work in one SQL query, just the update query by itself:

```
$insertSQL      =   "UPDATE store SET hits = hits+1 WHERE id = '$id'";
mysql_query($insertSQL);
```

Otherwise, you might end up losing some clicks.  You should also consider moving to PDO or `mysqli_` rather than using the deprecated `mysql_` functions.

> i think the problem is in defining the GET for this `<?= $store->id ?>`

Change it to `<?php echo $store->id; ?>` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `mysql_*` functions, they're deprecated use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Second, sanitize your inputs to avoid SQL Injection attacks. You can use `mysqli->prepare` and `bind_param` for that:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Then update directly at database level instead of retrieving it and then updating. Something like this should work:

```
"UPDATE store SET hits=hits+1 WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```